# ios DeviceToken: How to pass deviceToken from AppDelegate to ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am facing some strange issue. Actually viewController's ViewDidLoad method called before AppDelegate's `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method

**Code in AppDelegate is as follows**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"token:%@",newToken);
    NSUserDefaults *defaultValues = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaultValues setValue:newToken forKey:key_device_token];
    [defaultValues synchronize];
}
```

**Code of ViewDidLoad method**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSLog(@"ABCD");
}
```

**Following is Console output**

2

```
014-10-10 16:59:15.590 FollowMe[650:60b] ABCD
2014-10-10 16:59:15.592 FollowMe[650:60b] app dir: file:///var/mobile/Applications/94B3DF5E-B0CB-4F0B-99E7-2DFEBDC30ECB/Documents/
2014-10-10 16:59:15.693 FollowMe[650:60b] My token is: <3fff5f77 d15d7680 f8028b92 d1ebaf9b 06457115 336f1ee5 56172de6 5d8217c5>
2014-10-10 16:59:15.695 FollowMe[650:60b] token:3fff5f77d15d7680f8028b92d1ebaf9b06457115336f1ee556172de65d8217c5
```

Anyone can tell me what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, you registe your app for "Push Notification", and wait for a token from "Apple". When you receive it is normal your app create your **viewcontroller** first.

In the method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

inform you **viewcontroller** about the token. You have multiple options, find which is better for your app architecture.

If you need more details, a great tutorial about APNS:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1):

1. Use can save token in NSUserdefault, File, database (SQLite, Coredata, file etc...), Simple, you can keep it in the global variable, singleton...
2. You can use Push notification to notify when app delegate success register for remote notification.
3. you can define an protocol to listen the app delegate success register for remote notification.

Answer (score 0):

Set a delegate method in AppDelegate that you call when you finish `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.
Attach your controller to the delegate, as it'll be notified when the notification is registered.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"token:%@",newToken);
NSUserDefaults *defaultValues = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaultValues setValue:newToken forKey:key_device_token];
[defaultValues synchronize];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"profileUpdated" object:nil];
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(printDeviceID:)
                                                 name:@"profileUpdated"
                                               object:nil];
}


- (void) printDeviceID:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"profileUpdated"])
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaultValues = notification.info;

 }
}
```